# Get facts and print parameters in CLIPS

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips

I would like to print all the datas of the facts with a rule. Here are the facts :

```
(deffacts datas
(pile name 1 blocks A B C A B)
(pile name 2 blocks B A)
(pile name 3 blocks A B)
(pile name 4 blocks A))
```

And here are the printing I want to see :

```
pile 1 : A B C A B
pile 2 : B A
pile 3 : A B
pile 4 : A
```

Does somebody has an idea how to do it ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order in which the piles are printed doesn't matter, you can do it this way:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deffacts datas
   (pile name 1 blocks A B C A B)
   (pile name 2 blocks B A)
   (pile name 3 blocks A B)
   (pile name 4 blocks A))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print
   (pile name ?name blocks $?blocks)
   =>
   (printout t pile " " ?name " : " (implode$ ?blocks) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
pile 4 : A
pile 3 : A B
pile 2 : B A
pile 1 : A B C A B
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate pile
   (slot name)
   (multislot blocks))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts datas
   (pile (name 1) (blocks A B C A B))
   (pile (name 2) (blocks B A))
   (pile (name 3) (blocks A B))
   (pile (name 4) (blocks A)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print
   (pile (name ?name) (blocks $?blocks))
   =>
   (printout t pile " " ?name " : " (implode$ ?blocks) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
pile 4 : A
pile 3 : A B
pile 2 : B A
pile 1 : A B C A B
CLIPS>
```

If the order is important, you can do it using facts in the following manners, but this is either destructive in the first case or requires cleanup in the second case:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate pile
   (slot name)
   (multislot blocks))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts datas
   (pile (name 1) (blocks A B C A B))
   (pile (name 2) (blocks B A))
   (pile (name 3) (blocks A B))
   (pile (name 4) (blocks A)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print
   ?pile <- (pile (name ?name) (blocks $?blocks))
   (not (pile (name ?name2&:(< ?name2 ?name))))
   =>
   (retract ?pile)
   (printout t pile " " ?name " : " (implode$ ?blocks) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
pile 1 : A B C A B
pile 2 : B A
pile 3 : A B
pile 4 : A
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
For a total of 1 fact.
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate pile
   (slot name)
   (multislot blocks))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts datas
   (pile (name 1) (blocks A B C A B))
   (pile (name 2) (blocks B A))
   (pile (name 3) (blocks A B))
   (pile (name 4) (blocks A)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print
   (pile (name ?name) (blocks $?blocks))
   (not (and (pile (name ?name2&:(< ?name2 ?name)))
             (not (pile-printed ?name2))))
   =>
   (assert (pile-printed ?name))
   (printout t pile " " ?name " : " (implode$ ?blocks) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
pile 1 : A B C A B
pile 2 : B A
pile 3 : A B
pile 4 : A
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (pile (name 1) (blocks A B C A B))
f-2     (pile (name 2) (blocks B A))
f-3     (pile (name 3) (blocks A B))
f-4     (pile (name 4) (blocks A))
f-5     (pile-printed 1)
f-6     (pile-printed 2)
f-7     (pile-printed 3)
f-8     (pile-printed 4)
For a total of 9 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Finally, you can use the fact query functions to retrieve all the piles facts and then sort them to get the desired order:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deffunction pile-sort (?f1 ?f2)
   (> (fact-slot-value ?f1 name)
      (fact-slot-value ?f2 name)))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate pile
   (slot name)
   (multislot blocks))
CLIPS>       
(deffacts datas
   (pile (name 1) (blocks A B C A B))
   (pile (name 2) (blocks B A))
   (pile (name 3) (blocks A B))
   (pile (name 4) (blocks A)))
CLIPS>       
(defrule print
   =>
   (bind ?facts (find-all-facts ((?f pile)) TRUE))
   (bind ?facts (sort pile-sort ?facts))
   (progn$ (?f ?facts)
      (printout t pile " " (fact-slot-value ?f name) " : " 
                           (implode$ (fact-slot-value ?f blocks)) crlf)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run) 
pile 1 : A B C A B
pile 2 : B A
pile 3 : A B
pile 4 : A
CLIPS>
```